# Регулярное выражение (запрет английских букв)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго вечера всем. Помогите, пожалуйста, грамотно составить регулярное выражение. Мне нужно проверить поле чтобы нельзя было отправить форму где есть английские буквы, т.е всё остальное можно(символы, смайлы, русские буквы и т.д), а английские нельзя. Я сколько пробовал, php постоянно ругается(( Видимо плохо тему усвоил, пробовал сделать так:

```
array('text', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[А-Яа-я0-9]+$/', 'message'=>'Можно использовать только русские буквы.'),
```

Но оно не действует, ОДНАКО, если А-Яа-я заменить на A-Za-z то русский текст запрещает, а английский пускает.

Comment: array('text', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[а-яА-Я]+$/', 'message'=>'Можно использовать только русские буквы.'),

для тестов http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не хотите пускать только английский буквы, то регулярное выражение будет таким:

```
'pattern'=>'/^[^A-z]+$/'
```

Answer (score 3):

лучше использовать

```
[^a-zA-Z]+
```

потому что в

```
[^A-z]+
```

входят не только большие и маленькие латинские буквы, но и символы

```
[ \ ] ^ _ `
```

Answer (score 2):

на любой вкус и цвет [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx)